# Printer Driver installed but when I try to print it say no active jobs?

Tags: printing

I have an Epson WF-2530 and I am running ubuntu 18.04. I connected the printer to my laptop and added the printer then it went to automatically install the driver needed. I have tried printing test pages and whenever I do it says test page added as job  and then the printer say job completed. However the printer is not printing anything. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the appropriate drivers for the printer, sometimes the generic drivers just don't work